# LESS variable changes depending on context?

Tags: variables, less, subtraction

I'm trying to set the shorthand font value ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090340/less-css-and-font-shorthand)), but the variable I'm using for line-height is behaving weirdly; as if the variable is re-interpreted each time.
This is in LESS version 1.4.2

```
.info {
    @infoHeight: 22px;
    @infoTopPadding: 2px;
    @infoLineHeight: @infoHeight - @infoTopPadding;
    margin: @infoLineHeight;
    font: bold 13px~'/'@infoLineHeight Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Results in:

```
.info {
    margin: 20px;
    font: bold 13px / 22px - 2px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

So the same variable results in two different values depending on context. Is this intended behavior or could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in [Less >= 1.4.0](http://lesscss.org/) you need to use math operations in brackets by default** (thats's by design, but can be changed in the Less settings). Your code would work perfectly fine in older versions of Less.

So if you write in **Less**:

```
.info {
    @infoHeight: 22px;
    @infoTopPadding: 2px;
    @infoLineHeight: (@infoHeight - @infoTopPadding);
    margin: @infoLineHeight;
    font: bold 13px~'/'@infoLineHeight Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

the **CSS** output becomes:

```
.info {
  margin: 20px;
  font: bold 13px / 20px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

I hope this is your desired/expected outcome.