# How to write border-radius in less without dividing result

Tags: css, less, border, css-shapes

How can I write this css into less:

```
border-radius: 10px / 20px;
```

> normally css interpret something like :

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px 20px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px 20px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px 20px;
```

> but less compilers are dividing 10px/20px = 0.5px

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but isn't it possible to just leave out the "/" and have it compile as intended?

Comment: @ Maharkus actually is not working, because they interpret border top and bottom without that "/" .

Comment: possible duplicate of [LESS CSS and font shorthand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090340/less-css-and-font-shorthand) (and tens more Q about the same thing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be due to not having strict maths turned on in the compiler which tells it to only run maths within parenthesis.

An alternative is to trick the system into thinking its a normal string instead of a calculation.

```
border-radius: 10px ~"/" 20px;
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOddrR)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the entire in `~"..."` like

```
border-radius: ~"10px / 20px";
```

or you can use

```
border-radius: e("10px / 20px");
```

You can refer [string unquoting](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#string_unquoting)